# How to get prediction value based on certain parameters?

Tags: r, stat

R-Programming: I just created a general additive model (GAM) in smoothing spline with the ISLR library. My code for the following is:

```
gam11 = lm(wage~s(age,5)+year+education, data = Wage)
```

How do I exactly figure out the predicted value for the wage if I want:

- The year set to "2008"
- The age set to "49"
- The education set to "advanced degree"

Not necessarily looking for how to plot this, but the exact value. What should my code look like? Should I use predict()?

Comment: yes use predict and pass your fitted model and a data.frame containing `data.frame(age=49, year=2009, education=..)` and maybe education need to be the number of the level that represents `"advanced degree"` this can be achieved by `which(levels(Wage$education)=="advanced degree")`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Thanks, that was my inkling. But I’m having a difficult time encoding the exact structure of the code for passing the fitted model and data frame onto predict() - can you give some pointers here?

Comment: I couldn't find the `Wage` dataset so I used `mtcars`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use `predict`:

```r
lm(formula=wt ~ disp + qsec + carb, mtcars) -> lm.fit
# here you create a data.frame containing the values
newdata = data.frame(qsec=17.98, disp= 225, carb=2)
predict(lm.fit, newdata=newdata)
```

```
       1 
3.028772
```